# How can you create an object within a class using a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with creating properties in a class based on an array argument. How can you do this?

Please see the following so you can see what I'm trying to do:

```
function Person(colors) {  
    this.color = (function () {
        this.color = new Object();
        for (q=0; q<colors.length; ++q) {
            var r;
            switch (q) {
                case 0: r = "favorite"; break;
                case 1: r = "likes"; break;
                case 2: r = "hates"; break;
                default: r = q; break;
            }            
            this.color.r = colors[q];
        }
    }).call(this);
}

var people = {
    george: new Person(["blue", "yellow", "green"]),
    bob: new Person(["green", "purple", "white"])
};

console.log(people.george.color.favorite);
```

Basically I'm trying to do:

```
this.color = {
    favorite: colors[0],
    likes: colors[1],
    hates: colors[2]
};
```

using a for loop. Any ideas?

By the way, I'm not sure stating "this.color = new Object();" inside of this.color is actually valid, it's just something I tried. How else can you do it?

Comment: "using a for loop" --- any practical reason for that?

Comment: Why not just pass an object as parameter?

Comment: @Korey , any luck solving this? What did you end up doing"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're doing this, it doesn't seem particularly like a good idea.

What's wrong in your code is that you're not using bracket notation.

Change this:

```
this.color.r = colors[q];
```

To this:

```
this.color[r] = colors[q];
```

Bracket notation means 'access the property whose named is placed in the variable r' instead of 'access the property named r'.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pMeSt/)

I suggest that you consider using JavaScript literal object notation instead. Your entire code could be re-factored as:

```
var people = {
    george:{
        color:{favorite:"blue",likes:"yellow",hates:"green"}
    },
    bob:{
        color:{favorite:"green",likes:"purple",hates:"white"}
    }
};
```